# MetroUi Dynamic Form Validation attributes

Tags: javascript, html, metro-ui-css

Am using the metroUi framework to develop a form, capturing data through Google Appscript and into google spreadsheets.

The form reveals new questions, unhiding/hiding DIVs depending on prior answers.

The form validation attributes can easily be added and removed dynamically which I accomplish using select element events from these prior answers.

The problem I have is that the MetroUI framework color codes the boarders of 'Select' and 'Input' elements depending if they are "required" or not. e.g. Grey is optional, Blue is required.

If i dynamically adjust the 'data-validation' attribute this color coding doesnt seem to update.

Is there a way I can ensure it is rendered correctly so the UX is consistent?